# Getting A PHP Error was encountered

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, controller, notice

I am new to codeigniter and still learning. I want to show a single product from my database containing the table product which includes product_id,product_name etc tables.I have come up with a problem below

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined variable: id
>
> Filename: controllers/mysite.php
>
> Line Number: 37

**Below is my controller :**

```
public function product()

{   
    $this->load->model('products');
    $data['rows3'] = $this->products->product($id);
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/product-left');
    $this->load->view('mysite/product-content',$data);
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/product-related');
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/footer');


}
```

**Below is my model**

```
<?php
 class products extends CI_Model{

   function product($id){

    $q3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id  ='".$id."'");

    if($q3->num_rows() > 0){

        foreach($q3->result() as $row){

           $data[] = $row;

        }
        return $data;
        }       
    }   
}
```

Now i am really confused where to use that id, what am i missing. please help.

Comment: Where are you defining $id?

Comment: are you passing any value or id to the controller action via url?

Comment: That is where i am getting confused.. i want to match the $id with the product_id from the database table. And yes i am passing the product_id value in the url . so any product link clicked goes to that product_id in the end of the url

Answer (score 0):

in your controller $id is not defined.

```
$data['rows3'] = $this->products->product($id);
```

EDIT:

```
public function product()

{   

    $id = $_REQUEST['product']; // You have to receive id something like this. Because it is a controller action. Isn't it?

    $this->load->model('products');
    $data['rows3'] = $this->products->product($id);
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/product-left');
    $this->load->view('mysite/product-content',$data);
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/product-related');
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/footer');


}
```

Comment: As from the above code i have defined $id in the controller.

Comment: @BabarAli but what is going in $id?

Comment: im confused at this part..  i have not defined $id variable seperately .. how can i use it to match the query string of the product_id in the url. As i have defined it in the model in product($id) and also in the controller. Do i have to define it somewhere else too ??

Comment: @kiren Siva , bro tried that but getting  A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined index: product_id

Comment: http://localhost/final-project/index.php/mysite/product/5

Comment: $_REQUEST['product_id']; to $_REQUEST['product']

Comment: tried it @kiren Siva .. still getting the same error msg

Comment: If your link is like that `http://localhost/final-project/index.php/mysite/product/5` then make your controller function like this `public function product($id)` at controler

Comment: i did also try that.. but it did not work..  getting same error

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public function product()    
{   
    $this->load->model('products');
    $id = $this->uri->segment(6);
    $data['rows3'] = $this->products->product($id);
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/product-left');
    $this->load->view('mysite/product-content',$data);
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/product-related');
    $this->load->view('mysite/include/footer');
}
```

**in model:**

```
function product($iUserID)
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id  ='".$id."'");
    if($q->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $q->row_array();
    }
    else
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

Comment: pass some value to $id

Comment: yes when i pass pass some $id ='1'; or any other product_id value i get the desired product. But this is not dynamic,

Comment: that is why i am telling you that pass id value dynamically.

Comment: can you post HTML code also?

Comment: when you submit the form that time also pass the value for the product id

Comment: below is the html code  



<?php 

foreach($rows3 as $r3){

 ?>
         
        
        <h1><?php echo $r3->product_name; ?></h1>
        
        <?php } ?>

Comment: edit question and write proper HTML code.

Comment: where is product id?

Comment: There is no submit form .. Im trying to fetch product details from the database table named product_id .. this is the image of the site i have hovered mouse to show the link http://i60.tinypic.com/zsobc2.png  and below is the page where i am navigated , where the product is shown and http://i60.tinypic.com/xoocw8.png

Comment: do you want all products information?

Comment: $id = $this->uri->segment(6);
try this for id value.

Comment: tried it .. as i dont see the above error but i also dont see any product info fetched.. but i do get the second error from the 2nd pic posted above : 'A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: mysite/product-content.php'

Comment: see whether my query works or not. print_r the variable and exit.
you will get the data all related to product.

Comment: Finally Found MY Mistake .. i removed $id = $_REQUEST['product']; and all similar $id's and only passed $id  in function->model then function product($id) <--[controller] and lastly $data['rows3'] = $this->products->product($id); ... The error was in mysql query there was addition of concatinated "" . so the query now looks like below : $q3 = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM product WHERE product_id  ='.$id.'');

Comment: Thankyou all of you who helped me :) couldnt have done without your effort guyz .. love this site !!! This was my first question and got satisfied :) Special thanks to @nody , Kiren Shiva